# flutter chips and colors - Why is ChoiceChip so different

Tags: flutter, material-design

assume the following code

```
ChipTheme(
                data: theme.chipTheme.copyWith(
                  //labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  secondaryLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  //selectedColor: Colors.black,
                  secondarySelectedColor: Colors.grey[300],
                  //brightness: Brightness.light
                ),
                child:
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Chip(
                        //selected: currentLevel >= 1,
                        label: new Text("Level 1"),
                        avatar: new CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                          child: Text("1")
                        ),
                      ),
                      ChoiceChip(
                        selected: currentLevel >= 2,
                        label: new Text("Level 2"),
                        avatar: new CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                            child: Text("2")
                        ),
                      ),
                      ChoiceChip(
                        selected: currentLevel >= 3,
                        label: new Text("Level 3"),
                        avatar: new CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                            child: Text("3")
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
              ),
```

This results looks like this:

[image]

The first one is a simple Chip widget. This is what i want to have as "selected" ChoiceChip. But as you can see, the second Chip looks differently compared to the first one. Why is that? I am happy with the 3rd one which is a not-selected ChoiceChip. No matter what i do, i cant get the 2nd one to look like the first one because ChoiceChip seems to darken everything (the green avatar and also the background color).

The selected ChoiceChip doesnt even look like it is selected or active. It looks nearly as the unselected one (3rd one).

Thanks for any hints how to get the styling right.

Comment: you wants to make this single choice or multiple choice ?

Answer (score 10):

Behold, solution may seem frustrating to you. At least it frustrated me a lot until I figured it out.

A ChoceChip behaves like a button. Now a button expects a non-null onPressed parameter. Which, if not provided, renders the disabled state of button.

Similarly ChoiceChip expects a non-null onSelected parameter. So a valid ChoiceChip declaration looks like below:

```
ChoiceChip(
    selected: currentLevel >= 2,
    label: new Text("Level 2"),
    avatar: new CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        child: Text("2")
    ),
    onSelected: (value) {}
),
```

And voila, you have the pretty looking ChoiceChips.

Comment: `onSelected`!! is the key!

Comment: God, save me a day